# issue with calling method from @selector with two parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to get id and and another parameter from @selector?? , im trying by this but not working!

```
-(void)displayContent:(UIViewController *)currentView sender:(id)sender{}
```

and

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(displayContent:self:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Selectors do NOT call methods, it simply **names** a method. A *very* important distinction to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide: Communicating with Objects: Target-Action in UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW44)

> the UIKit framework allows three different forms of action selector:
>
> `- (void)action`
>
> `- (void)action:(id)sender`
>
> `- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Your method `-displayContent:sender:` does not match any of those signatures, so it is not valid for passing to `-[UIControl addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]`. You'll have to find another way of getting `currentView` into your action, probably by using an instance variable to keep track of the current view.

Comment: thnks...i had found another way!